# Не компилируется Release версия проекта

Tags: c#, wpf

Не понимаю где искать ошибку
Debug отрабатывает отлично.

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" в PresentationFramework.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Задание свойства
>   "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.Value" вызвало
>   исключение.
>
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException не обработано Message:
>   Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" в PresentationFramework.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Задание свойства
>   "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.Value" вызвало
>   исключение.

Не доходит до

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Не доходит до

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        App()
        { 
        }
    }
```

Да Убрал "Только мой код" и пошли ошибки

> ополнительные сведения: Сборка "WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap" была загружена
>   из
>   "file:///C:/Users/7636~1/AppData/Local/Temp/VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.9236/WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll"
>   с помощью контекста LoadFrom. Использование этого контекста может
>   привести к неожиданному поведению при сериализации, приведении типов и
>   разрешении зависимостей. Почти во всех случаях рекомендуется избегать
>   использования контекста LoadFrom. Этого можно добиться, устанавливая
>   сборки в Global Assembly Cache или в каталог ApplicationBase и
>   используя Assembly.Load при явной загрузке сборок.
>
> {"Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.
>   (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}

Comment: Покажите ваш код XAML

Comment: проверьте ваши свойства, может компилятору не понятно AccelerationRatio=".9" и надо задавать как AccelerationRatio="0.9". Не говорит строку на которую ругается?

Comment: @user2455111 Он не доходит до InitializeComponent(), значит это точно не XAML

Comment: А `Value` у вас нигде не привязывается? Никаких `ProgressBar`, например?

Comment: Приведите еще полный текст ошибки о стеком вызовов, пожалуйста

Comment: AccelerationRatio=".9"  исправил - не изменилось ничего

Comment: В стеке вызовов "Внешний код"  - больше нет ничего

Comment: что в `Inner Exception` у Вас?

Comment: я не могу отловить. Ошибка приходит до запуска

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx настройте отладку для релиз версии

Comment: @ user2455111 это для c++

Comment: может в call stack что то видно будет, ну или как вариант, добавлять код  в Xaml блоками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас компилируется Debug и не компилируется Release, значит скорее всего не хватает какой-то библиотеки. Сравните содержимое папок debug и release, скопируйте недостающие файлы в release.

Comment: Я тоже думал над этим. Есть bass.dll с которой были проблемы в debug. Bass.Net.dll подключена через ссылку, a bass.dll лежит в корне проекта и компилируется как "Содержание". Но в любом случае она появляется при сборке в папке

Comment: @АнульевПавел Проверьте еще соответствие разрядности, попробуйте x86 поставить

Comment: x64,x86,Anu CPU - все тоже самое

Comment: @АнульевПавел Попробуйте еще для bass.dll установить свойства: действие при сборке - нет, копировать в выходной каталог - всегда копировать

Comment: Сделал - такая же ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы отловить ошибку, Вам необходимо отловить исключение на этапе его появления. Для этого в VisualStudio Вам необходимо нажать комбинацию клавиш:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Затем, в появившемся окне поставить галочку на строке `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`, хотя, на всех чек-боксах поставьте галочку, возможно не только ее нужно поставить, насколько я помню, вот тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого Вы сможете заглянуть в `Inner Exception` и сможете отловить ошибку.

> Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Вот тут вроде бы проясняется суть проблемы. Проблема в том, что какая-то библиотека отказывается работать под х64, так она 32-битной сборки. Думаю, что все же проблема в настройках сборки. Идем в `Configuration Manager`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заходим внутрь и что делаем, видим (это к примеру):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И делаем для `Release` такие же настройки сборки в проектах и решении.

А еще идем сюда:

<kbd>Project Properties</kbd> --> <kbd>Build</kbd> --> <kbd>Platform Target</kbd>

И смотрим, что у нас в `Debug` и в `Release`, ищем отличия и исправляем. Думаю  **x86** должно решить проблему.

---

Решение проблемы оказалось тривиальным. Как выяснилось, причиной того, что сборка не проходила было то, что были библиотеки, скомпилированные под 64 и 32-битные разрядности. Что потребовалось сделать, чтобы построение проекта заработало: очистить решение, восстановить NuGet-пакеты (так как у меня их не было), в настройках постройки решения и в `Debug` и в `Release` необходимо было поставить `Any CPU`. Переоткрыть `VisualStudio` (для автора вопроса). После чего постройка проекта заработала в обеих конфигурациях.

Comment: Добавил скрин. Не могу вытащить больше информации об ошибке. Или не вижу тупо

Comment: @АнульевПавел, что с библиотеками в папках, в конце ответа дописал.

Comment: @DenisBubnov я вот про то же

Comment: Bass не хочет работать.

Comment: @АнульевПавел, в таком случае Вам нужно зайти в `Configuration Manager` в свойствах сборки. Сейчас добавлю в ответ, скажу как и что сделать.

Comment: @DenisBubnov на x86 debug теперь даже не работает. И то сначала выдает ошибку

Comment: Сборка "WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap" была загружена из "file:///C:/Users/7636~1/AppData/Local/Temp/VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.9236/WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll" с помощью контекста LoadFrom.  При этом Bass.Net работает. После закрытия приходит ошибка Помощник отладки управляемого кода "NotMarshalable" обнаружил неполадку в "C:\Users\Павел\Documents\GitHub\AnastasiaAssistant\AnastasiaAssistant\bin\x64\Debug\Anastasia.vshost.exe".

Дополнительные сведения: Используется неупаковываемый COM-компонент из другого апартамента или контекста, чем тот, из которого впервые был осуществлен доступ к CLR.

Comment: @АнульевПавел, ты не для `Debug` меняй, а для `Release`, просто выставь такие же настройки. У решения не меняй настроек пока, просто для сборок сделай.

Comment: я так и сделал. Но походу когда я отключил только мой код и debug полетел. В любом случае Release не запускается без ошибок при любой архитектуре

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием глянул что не так, интересно разобраться. Может на Github или Bitbucket зальешь проект? Попробую вечером помочь тогда )